# QPushButton - Execute while loop until Pushbutton is not clicked

Tags: c++, qt, while-loop, can-bus, qpushbutton

I have implemented a GUI and my problem is to handle two tasks at the same time. My code should be provide the opportunity to execute the task by clicking on a Pushbutton or by listening to CAN messages with the read function.

I had the idea to read CAN messages with a while loop until the pushbutton is clicked. Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

Your GUI itself should have some sort of main loop that continuously runs waiting for any updates to process. Each iteration of which, it should be reading the CAN messages and if there is a trigger for a specific task, you should have code implemented that handles that. The same thing goes for any of your push buttons. You should not have any logic that stops checking the CAN if a button is pushed, or vice-versa. Instead, you should keep track of specific events being triggered with a boolean and prevent retriggering them until they are complete/resolved.

Comment: @SinanKiris You could use a [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#details) to trigger periodical calls of your CAN read stuff instead of a while loop. So, the main event loop becomes your while loop with the advantage that other events (like e.g. your button click) will be considered as well. You even could set the timeout for this `QTimer` to 0 if necessary. Then the timer becomes an idle callback which is called as long as no other event occurs. However, I would make the idle callback the last resort because you will notice that this causes high CPU load (with a loud cooler noise).